# How to allocate unclassified observations proportionally within classified data?

Tags: r, proportion

In my dataset, about 30 percent of all observations belong to a unclassified category. Since I want to account for the effect of these observations, I want to allocate these unclassified observations proportionally to other indicators. How is the standard approach to solve such an issue, using R?

My dataset - before spreading - looks like this:

[image]

After spreading, it looks like this, whilst one variable obtains all unclassified observations:

[image]

Concretely, I want to reallocate the variable Unspecified among all other indicators.

Comment: Could you please say more about why you think that spreading the "Unspecified" among the other categories would be an appropriate way to proceed? I note, for example, that all 652 cases for AUS in 2004 are in that category, while the proportion of "Unpecified" to "All" is much lower in the other examples. There seem to be some systematic differences among values of Country that would be lost by proceeding as you propose.

Comment: It's mainly because it was done as such in another scientific study, I want to replicate. The justification is also that I need to account for 'unspecified' since the observations account for about 30 percent of all values. Since there is no better data, I make a basic assumption, that the unspecified values are distributed equally among all other indicators. Note, that the indicator 'All Industries' is just the total of agriculture, mining, manufacturing, utilities, etc. I'm happy for your further advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to repeat another study, then you should proceed as they did with respect to "Unspecified" cases first. Then, if you believe that their approach could be improved, show a comparison of the approaches.

Before you try to spread out the "Unspecified" into other categories, look carefully at the data and decide on the extent to which that is the best way to proceed.

In the displayed data for 2004, the 652 "Unspecified" cases just for `AUS` represent all of the `AUS` cases for that year (*none* were classified) and account for 4.4% of all the 2004 "Unspecified" cases. Yet the displayed data evidently represent only about 1% of the cases (based on displaying 10 out of 975 rows). In comparison, the displayed Manufacturing cases represent 1.3% of the 2004 Manufacturing cases, more in keeping with the fraction of the displayed data to the total. I suspect that some particular countries simply did not classify cases into categories. You might be better off identifying and removing such countries, as it's not at all clear that they will be behaving similarly to other countries in other respects, either. That choice depends on judgment based on your knowledge of the subject matter.

That will still leave some lower fraction of "Unspecified" cases from other countries, however. So if these cases really do belong in one of the other categories but just weren't categorized, then you could distribute them in some way proportional to the prevalence of cases among the categories. Simplest, but least desirable, would be simply to use the corresponding overall fractions of categorized cases. For example, education/research/development for 2004 represented 0.375% of the categorized cases, so you would assign that percentage of the 14714 Unspecified cases to that category for 2004, or 55 cases. You might want to do this on a year-by-year basis to account for trends with time.

Another approach, in line with the idea of [multiple imputation](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/), would be to use [multinomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multinomial/info) sampling of the Unspecified cases into the categories, based on the probabilities of the different categories.* You would produce a few tens or hundreds sets of the data, each based on a different random distribution of the Unspecified cases into the categories. You would perform your analysis on each of the sets of data, then pool results among the data sets to take the variability introduced by the imputations into account.

The approaches I just suggested make the assumption that the distribution of these types of cases among countries are all the same. If you have other economic or demographic data, you could go so far as to include such data along with these data to develop a [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) model for distributing Unspecified cases that takes time and country-specific economic data into account. That, together with sampling for multiple imputations, would probably be the most reliable approach.

It would be best to try to find some local econometric/statistical help on this, as there are many ways to go wrong in the implementation of these techniques.